# Android - How to check if textview is null or not null

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I have some textview in my application
and want to check whether the properties of text on my textview has a value or null.
then i want to display a toast if the value on my textview null

but the toast is not running as it should

this is my code :

```
public class brekeleV2 extends Activity {
static Context context;
brekeleV2Model r = new brekeleV2Model();
private EditText jalan, kota, postal;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    context = getApplicationContext();
    Button go = (Button)findViewById(R.id.go);
    go.setOnClickListener(onGo);

    Button reset = (Button)findViewById(R.id.reset);
    reset.setOnClickListener(onRes);
    jalan =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.jalan);
    kota =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.kota);
    postal =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.post);
    jalan.setText(null);
    kota.setText(null);
    postal.setText(null);
}
```

and this is the onClick method code:

```
private View.OnClickListener onGo=new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (jalan.getText()!= null && kota.getText()!=null){
            switch(v.getId()){
                case R.id.go:
                    Intent maps = new Intent();
                    maps.setClassName("com.openit.brekele", "com.openit.brekele.brekeleV2Nav");
                    brekeleV2Nav.putLatLong(lat, lon);
                    startActivity(maps);
                    break;

            }
        }else{
            Toast msg = Toast.makeText(brekeleV2.this, "Lengkapi Data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            msg.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, msg.getXOffset() / 2, msg.getYOffset() / 2);
            msg.show();
        }
```

Answer (score 25):

```
if(!textview.getText().toString.matches(""))
{
    // not null not empty
}else {
    //null or empty
}
```

Comment: i try and still didnt. work.
this is my code :

if (!jalan.getText().equals("") && !kota.getText().equals("")){
    switch(v.getId()){
     case R.id.go:
      Intent maps = new Intent();
      maps.setClassName("com.openit.razer", "com.openit.razer.mapRazerNav");
      mapRazerNav.putLatLong(lat, lon);
      startActivity(maps);
      break;
      
    }
   }else{
    Toast msg = Toast.makeText(razerNav.this, "Lengkapi Data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    msg.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, msg.getXOffset() / 2, msg.getYOffset() / 2);
    msg.show();
   }

Comment: change your code in question it self.. will be readable.. will help you more then

Comment: try showing toast without setting gravity and or add logs here..have your tried it. i hope it will work

Answer (score 5):

This is what I would use.

```
if (mText1.getText().length() > 0 && mText2.getText().length() > 0) {
   // Your code.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

in the end i found my problem solving. here is my code:

```
if (jalan.getText().toString().length()>0 || kota.getText().toString().length()>0){
            //switch(v.getId()){
                //case R.id.go:
                    Intent maps = new Intent();
                    maps.setClassName("com.openit.razer", "com.openit.razer.mapRazerNav");
                    mapRazerNav.putLatLong(lat, lon);
                    startActivity(maps);
                    //break;

            //}
        }else{
            Toast msg = Toast.makeText(razerNav.this, "Lengkapi Data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            msg.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, msg.getXOffset() / 2, msg.getYOffset() / 2);
            msg.show();

        }
```

i used to check the length, because on my xml i add like this :

```
android:text=" "
```

see? this is my fault.
anyway thanks for helping me. :)

Answer (score 1):

[TextView has a public length() method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#length()) you can use to check if there are any characters in the TextView.

```
    if (textView.length() > 0) {
        // textView is not null
    } else {
        // textView is null
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `textView.getText() != ""` instead.

Comment: And what if the text in TextView will be "" ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the else condition is invoked? Debug it!

Maybe you need to put the toast into a runOnUiThread statement:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        mText.setText("Hello there, " + name + "!");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Method getText() in TextView returns EditAble that cant compare with String
you should convert EditAble to String using String.ValueOf() method.

```
String jalanContent = String.ValueOf(jalan.getText());
if(jalanContent.equals(""){
//do your action here
} else {
//some action here
}
```

hope it'd be usefull

Answer (score 0):

***if (jalan.getText()!= null && kota.getText()!=null)***
This is the line of code that doesn't work for you. 
Best solution for such scenario is using `matches("")`  method for **String**

So the solution will be:

```
     if (!jalan.getText().toString.matches("") && !kota.getText().toString().matches("")){
   // code for not null textViews 
}
else
{
//Code for nul textView
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have modified the correct answer a bit (missing `()` after `toString` but we're not allowed edit code so:

```
if(textview.getText().toString().matches(""))
{
    // is null or empty
}else {
    //not null or empty
}
```